# How to extract messages to translate from a Play! application

Tags: playframework, internationalization, naming-conventions

I'm writing my first application using the Play! framework and I was wondering if there was a tool that could extract the messages that need translation from my views and controllers for me ? It is rather cumbersome to fill the conf/messages(.xx) file while I'm developing my app, but I'm afraid that if I don't do it as I go, I will never be able to completely translate my application afterwards.

Such tools exist with other framework such as CakePHP for instance, and I think that it shouldn't be hard to write one by myself, but if there already is one...

I was also wondering, what should I name the keys of the messages in my application ? Using gettext, it's not bad practice to directly type in the message in english as the key, but is it with the system that Play! uses (MessageFormat, right ?) ? Does anyone have an advice or naming convention (something like controller.action.describe_the_message maybe) ?

Thank you for your advices !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small tool that automatically extracts the calls to Messages that are present in the source code and the templates of a Play! application to create the conf/messages.xx files for all the languages that you've defined into the configuration of your application.

You can find it here : https://github.com/Duhemm/PlayMessagesExtractor

Please note that the implementation is not very efficient as of today, but I plan on improving it in later releases.

I hope this will be useful to someone !

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK there's no such tool and I agree it would be helpful one.

There's also no naming convention for translation keys, anyway your suggestion is clean approach and should help translating especially in bigger projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've started writing a simple "extractor" for the messages. For the moment, it will simply overwrite your existing messages.xx, but I will change that shortly. I do not have much experience with Play!, so this program may miss messages. If you have time, could you take a look at the source and tell me what it may miss ? The source is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/Duhemm/PlayMessagesExtractor). Thank you very much !